# Как передать данные State в Callback?

Tags: python, telegram, aiogram

```
from aiogram import Bot, Dispatcher, types
from aiogram.contrib.fsm_storage.memory import MemoryStorage
from aiogram.dispatcher import FSMContext
from aiogram.dispatcher.filters import Text
from aiogram.dispatcher.filters.state import State, StatesGroup
from aiogram.types import ParseMode
from aiogram.utils import executor


API_TOKEN = "TOKEN"
bot = Bot(token=API_TOKEN)
storage = MemoryStorage()
dp = Dispatcher(bot, storage=storage)


class Form(StatesGroup):
    name = State()
    age = State()

@dp.message_handler(commands='start')
async def cmd_start(message: types.Message):

    await Form.name.set()
    await message.reply("Your name?")


@dp.message_handler(state=Form.name)
async def process_name(message: types.Message, state: FSMContext):
    async with state.proxy() as data:
        data["name"] = message.text
    await Form.next()
    await message.reply("How old are you?")


@dp.message_handler(state=Form.age)
async def process_age(message: types.Message, state: FSMContext):
    async with state.proxy() as data:
        data["age"] = message.text

    await state.finish()
    keyboard = types.InlineKeyboardMarkup()
    keyboard.add(types.InlineKeyboardButton(text = "Click the button", callback_data = "send_storage"))
    await bot.send_message(message.from_user.id, "Click me", reply_markup = keyboard)

@dp.callback_query_handler(state = Form)
async def process_callback(call, state: FSMContext):
    if call.data == "send_storage":
        print("Here")
        #И сюда нужно вывести name и age

if __name__ == "__main__":
    executor.start_polling(dp, skip_updates=True)
```

Answer (score 0):

Добавить еще одно состояние:

```
fin = State()
```

потом, вместо

```
state.finish() -> Form.next()
```

и последний обработчик так

```
@dp.callback_query_handler(text = 'send_storage', state=Form.fin)
async def process_callback(call: types.CallbackQuery, state: FSMContext):
    await call.answer()
    if call.data == "send_storage":
        print("Here")
        print(await state.get_data())
        #И сюда нужно вывести name и age
        await state.finish()
```